# Get all protected tasks in an AWS service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

We have implemented scale-in protection on our ECS service. I want to retrieve all tasks in a service with **protectionEnabled** as true. Gone through all documentation but it looks no any direct API which will give the list..

Tried for https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/get-task-protection.html.
get-task-protection. But its expecting all tasks(array of tasks Ids which are running in service).

But what I need is

get-task-protection (where I give cluster name and service service name),  which will give all tasks in a service.

Please share your ideas.